# What is the best way to Update/Add/Delete multiple records in the same form with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I have this Topic table who is linked to the table Post with hasMany in the model.

This is my $this->request->data

```
Array
(
[Topic] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [topic_title] => This is my topic
    )

[Post] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [title] => Blah
                [message] => My message
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [title] => Second Blah
                [message] => Second My message
            )

    )

)
```

And I update it with :

```
$this->Topic->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
```

But What if I also wanted to have the ability to add and delete posts to this topic, how would I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the same structure, you could do a `$this->Topic->saveAssociated($this->request->data);` and it will add any new (`'id' => NULL` or unset) items in the data array.

About the delete, the only case I know would delete at the same time, would be a HABTM when it's marked as `'unique' => true`. Otherwise, you need to do a `$this->Post->deleteAll(array('Post.topic_id' => $unwanted_topic_id), false);`

I could think of making a new array keeping the ones you want deleted and sending them as condition for the deleteAll function.

Answer (score 0):

**From CakePHP 2 Book**

```
delete(integer $id = null, boolean $cascade = true);
```

> Deletes the record identified by $id. By default, also deletes records
>   dependent on the record specified to be deleted.
>
> For example, when deleting a User record that is tied to many Recipe
>   records (User ‘hasMany’ or ‘hasAndBelongsToMany’ Recipes):
>
> - if $cascade is set to true, the related Recipe records are also deleted if the model’s dependent-value is set to true.
> - if $cascade is set to false, the Recipe records will remain after the User has been deleted.

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html**

Comment: I don't understand how to only delete a post (or more than one) but keeping the Topic. In the controller I only have access to the Topic model.